# ¿Cómo decir que algo está mal aunque parezca estar bien?

Tags: expresiones

Estoy tratando de decir que algo está mal aunque parezca estar bien. ¿Alguna de las siguientes frases tiene sentido?

> No confíe en esas sonrisas y palabras amables. Yo sé lo que ellas
> **tienen de rencor**.
>
> No confíe en esas sonrisas y palabras amables. Yo sé lo que ellas
> **llevan de rencor**.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la frase del ejemplo, yo usaría el verbo [esconder](https://dle.rae.es/esconder):

- No confíe en esas sonrisas y palabras amables. Yo sé lo que **esconden**

o

- No confíe en esas sonrisas y palabras amables. Yo sé lo que **se esconde detrás de ellas**

o incluso, si se sabe que lo que realmente sienten esas personas es [rencor](https://dle.rae.es/rencor?m=form):

- No confíe en esas sonrisas y palabras amables. Yo conozco el **rencor que esconden**

Estas frases indican que hay una intención oculta detrás de esas sonrisas. Una expresión más general (que no implica intención) es *las apariencias engañan*:

- En público son muy cariñosos el uno con el otro, pero **las apariencias engañan**: en casa están siempre peleando.

Comment: También se puede usar el dicho: "No todo lo que brilla es oro" (https://www.significados.com/no-es-oro-todo-lo-que-reluce/)

Comment: I have heard this.  Aquí, ni son todos los que están ni están todos los que son.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba un:

No confíe en esas sonrisas y palabras amables, no siempre son herramientas nobles.

o

No confíe en esas sonrisas y palabras amables. Muchos tiranos las usan a diario.

Answer (score 1):

*Esas sonrisas y palabras amables **son fingidas.***

Meaning: feigned, contrived, hypocritical, false